# unit testing a java method by calling the method in multiple threads

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have a spring bootproject with several services. Im writing junit test for a method that defines a service that reads value from database and updates it with the new value in the database. I want to do unit testing for the method by calling it in 10 different threads. How can this be done?

Comment: In your test, start ten threads, have them each do what they need to do, then `join` them. Sprinkle assertions along the way (maybe within the threads, maybe after the `join`).

Comment: what you want is an integration test, not an unit test. Testing multithreading only in the repository scope is probably not enough because transaction and logic have side effect on.